# +x permission for files in directory

Tags: permissions, files

I'm an Ubuntu user and I'd like to change default permissions for downloaded files. Currentely all downloaded files are automatically saved with "-rw-r--r--" permissions (umask 0022). I'd like to add "+x". How to do that?

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Related: [facl ignoring the “x” permission but only on files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/234080).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to edit the source code of the programs performing the downloading as files are created by default as 0666 modified by the current umask. From the `fopen(3)` man page:

> ```
>    Any created files will have mode S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP |  S_IWGRP
>    |  S_IROTH  |  S_IWOTH (0666), as modified by the process’s umask value
>    (see umask(2)).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

which program do you use to download? If the program doesn't have hard permission for new files compiled in, you can simply set the environments umask before starting the program (in the same env / shell).

With bash there is a "umask" command, try 'help umask' in bash.

e.g. umask 0000; wget htpp://