# Why doesn't the owning group get the executable bit?

Tags: linux, ext4, acl

Playing with ACL's:

```
[root@rex web]# pwd
/media/web
[root@rex web]# ll -d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  1 14:31 .
[root@rex web]# setfacl -m d:g::rwx .
[root@rex web]# setfacl -m g::rwx .
[root@rex web]# touch newTest
[root@rex web]# getfacl newTest
# file: newTest
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
[root@rex web]# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Simple question I'm just not able to answer it. If the executable bit is in the group's default ACL why isn't it showing up in the resulting file. I thought my `umask` setting was at fault but got the same result there:

```
[root@rex web]# umask
0022
[root@rex web]# umask 0000
[root@rex web]# touch anotherTest
[root@rex web]# getfacl anotherTest
# file: anotherTest
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

I'm sure it's intentional, I just don't understand it.

Tried to see if it was just something specific to the primary group but then a `mask` started showing up in my ACL's for some reason:

```
[root@rex web]# setfacl -m g:web:rwx .
[root@rex web]# setfacl -m d:g:web:rwx .
[root@rex web]# touch newer
[root@rex web]# getfacl newer
# file: newer
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
group:web:rwx                   #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

I'd imagine this is why it isn't showing up above, but my questions are:

1) Why doesn't "mask" show up before I specify a group other than the primary group?

2) Where is this mask coming from? I'm not seeing it on any parent directory.

Comment: `touch` does a `open("anotherTest", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666)` (not `0777`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I get same result if I do a `echo hey > this`

Comment: Same `>` never request the execution bit. Generally applications don't request the execution bit unless there're meant to create executable files (like `ld`, `gcc`).

Comment: OK, but where is the mask setting coming from then?

Comment: That's something else, see `man acl`

Comment: Right but what I meant to say was that it looks like there's a mask setting coming into play at some point. I updated my question a which ago, i don't know if you've seen the update.

Comment: Another related one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165240/facl-ignoring-the-x-permission-but-only-on-files/165304#165304

Comment: @mikel OK I get that point but where is the mask setting coming from?

Comment: The question isn't a duplicate. My question is about how the mask setting is getting in there. The stuff in that other thread is about the first part of the question and we're ignoring the other two parts.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: What would have been the benefit to separating this out for each of these parts? They're each about the same thing.