# Cygwin inheritance of Windows's security for cross-account file creation/modificaton?

Tags: permissions, security, acl, cygwin, file-management

On a Windows 10 laptop, I have an administrator account `Admin`, a
non-administrator account `User.Name`, and the default `Public`
account.

From either `Admin` or `User.Name` accounts, files created in the `~/`
tree have read/write permission for the *user* but not the *group*.
The command `ls -l` shows the group to be `None`.  In the following
examples, the commands were issued in a different order than shown
here, so the time stamps aren't very informative.

Example from `~/tmp` of `User.Name` account:

```
User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ echo "Hello" > Test.txt

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ zip Test.zip Test.txt
  adding: Test.txt (stored 0%)

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ ls -l Test.{txt,zip}
-rw------- 1 User.Name None   6 2023-08-11 00:42 Test.txt
-rw------- 1 User.Name None 172 2023-08-11 01:05 Test.zip
```

Example from `~/tmp` of `Admin` account:

```
Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ echo "Hello" > Test.txt

Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ zip Test.zip Test.txt
  adding: Test.txt (stored 0%)

Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ ls -l Test.{txt,zip}
-rw------- 1 Admin None   6 2023-08-11 00:44 Test.txt
-rw------- 1 Admin None 172 2023-08-11 01:02 Test.zip
```

From account `User.Name` or `Admin`, however, if I create files in the
`/c/Users/Public/` tree, both the user *and* the group have read/write
permission.

Example from `~/tmp` of the `User.Name` account:

```
User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$echo "Hello" > /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromUser.Name.txt

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$zip /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromUser.Name.zip Test.txt
  adding: Test.txt (stored 0%)

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ls -l /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromUser.Name.{txt,zip}
-rw-rw----+ 1 User.Name None   6 2023-08-11 00:52 /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromUser.Name.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 User.Name None 172 2023-08-11 00:53 /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromUser.Name.zip
```

Example from `~/tmp` of the `Admin` account:

```
Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ echo "Hello" > /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromAdmin.txt

Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ zip /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromAdmin.zip Test.txt
  adding: Test.txt (stored 0%)

Admin@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ ls -l /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromAdmin.{txt,zip}
-rw-rw----+ 1 Admin None   6 2023-08-11 00:47 /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromAdmin.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 Admin None 172 2023-08-11 00:47 /c/Users/Public/tmp/TestFromAdmin.zip
```

I confirmed the more open permissions by creating a zip file
`/c/Users/Public/tmp/Test.zip` from the `User.Name` account. I can
subsequently use Cygwin's `zip` command to add files to
`/c/Users/Public/tmp/Test.zip` from the `Admin` account.  Furthermore,
I can subsequently use Cygwin's `zip` command add files to
`/c/Users/Public/tmp/Test.zip` from the `User.Name` account.

This is the behaviour that I find most convenient, but since I'm not
using Windows Explorer, I wonder ***how Cygwin knows to make files in
the /c/User/Public file tree readable and writable by both the user
and the group?***  Where in the documentation should I focus on to
understand this?

I looked through the documentation on [POSIX accounts, permission, and
security](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html), but
frankly much of it delves into a lot of detail that I don't have the
grounding to understand.  I was wondering whether there might be a
simpler high-level description of behaviour, such as "Cygwin interacts
with Windows at such-and-such a level to inherit the security
behaviour for cross-account creation and modification of files".  A
concise expression of the designed-for behaviour would help users
understand what to expect under different cross-account operations.

## Troubleshooting

To keep the troubleshooting manageable, I note that the difference
seems to be bewteen files written in a user's own file space versus
`Public`'s file space.  Therefore, I compare `User.Name` writing to
`User.Name`'s file space versus `User.Name` writing to `Public`'s file
space, i.e., I dispense with the comparison with `Admin`.

Based on *G-Man's* suggestions, I tested whether the different
permissions were due to writing files in the Cygwin file tree rooted
at `/home` rather than the larger Windows file tree rooted at
`/c/Users`.  It appears to be unrelated, which confirms that the
different permissions are due to writing across to the `Public`
account rather than writing to the `/c/Users` tree vs. the `/home`
tree.

```
User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # Permissions of one's Cygwin home directory.
$ # Not sure how relevant this is.
$ ls -ld ~
drwxr-xr-x 1 User.Name None 0 Aug 12 13:13 /home/User.Name

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # Permissions of one's own current directory.
$ # Not sure how relevant this is.
$ ls -ld ~/tmp
drwx------ 1 User.Name None 0 Aug 12 02:20 /home/User.Name/tmp

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # Permissions of file created in one's own Windows file tree.
$ # Only "User" has read/write access.
$ ls > /c/Users/User.Name/Documents/List.txt
$ ls -l /c/Users/User.Name/Documents/List.txt
-rw-------+ 1 User.Name None 414 2023-08-12 13:19 /c/Users/User.Name/Documents/List.txt

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # Permissions of file created in Public's Windows file tree
$ # Both "User" and "Group" have read/write access.
$ ls > /c/Users/Public/Documents/List.txt
$ ls -l /c/Users/Public/Documents/List.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 User.Name None 414 2023-08-12 13:20 /c/Users/Public/Documents/List.txt
```

I was also advised to apply `getfacl` to the folders containing the
files being compared.  Here are the results of `getfacl` for a user's
Cygwin "tmp" folder, a user's Windows "Documents" folder, and
`Public`'s "Documents" folder:

```
User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # FACL for user's Cygwin "tmp" folder
$ getfacl ~/tmp
# file: /home/User.Name/tmp
# owner: User.Name
# group: None
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::r-x

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # FACL for user's Windows "Documents" folder
$ getfacl /c/Users/User.Name/Documents/
# file: /c/Users/User.Name/Documents/
# owner: User.Name
# group: None
user::rwx
group::---
group:SYSTEM:rwx        #effective:---
group:Administrators:rwx        #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:SYSTEM:rwx        #effective:---
default:group:Administrators:rwx        #effective:---
default:mask::---
default:other::---

User.Name@Laptop-Hostname ~/tmp
$ # FACL for Public's Windows "Documents" folder
$ getfacl /c/Users/Public/Documents/
# file: /c/Users/Public/Documents/
# owner: SYSTEM
# group: SYSTEM
user::rwx
group::---
group:BATCH:rwx
group:INTERACTIVE:rwx
group:SERVICE:rwx
group:Administrators:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:SYSTEM:rwx
default:group::---
default:group:BATCH:rwx
default:group:INTERACTIVE:rwx
default:group:SERVICE:rwx
default:group:Administrators:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

I read up about FACLs
[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022035645/http://vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/POSIX_ACL_on_Linux.html).
I note that "named users" and "named groups" *both* belong to the
"group class".  The *effective* permissions are the minimum  (bit-wise
ANDing) of the named user/group permission bits with a 3-bit "mask".
This corroborates with the presence of `#effective:---` above.
According to the text, the group permissions from `ls -l` are those of
the *mask*, which  may be more or less permissive than any specific
named user/group.

Counterintuitively, the *owning* group's permissions are *not* ANDed
with the mask (if I understood the text correctly).

I make two assumptions in interpreting the text: (1) that the "owning"
group is the group to which the owner user belongs and (2) the group
`None` corresponds to the FACL entries leading with `group::`.

The first `getfacl` above is for `/home/User.Name/tmp`.  The `default`
entries explain why newly created files have user read/write
permissions, but *not* why new files lack execute permission (`x`).
Furthermore, the `default` entries are inconsistent with the fact that
new files lack group/other read and execute permissions.

The next `getfacl` is for `/c/Users/User.Name/Documents/`.  The
default `---` entries *do* explain why group/other have no permissions
for newly created files.

The third and final `getfacl` is for `/c/Users/Public/Documents/`.
The `default:user::rwx` entry does explain why a user such as
`User.Name` has read/write access to a file created by `User.Name` --
*assuming that `user` refers to the owner/creator of the file rather
than the directory.*  The `default:group:Administrators:rwx` entry
also explains why the `Admin` account could add to a Zip file created
by `User.Name`.  A confirmation of the correctness of this reasoning
would be appreciated (and would constitute an answer, if one wishes
to post it as the answer).

Comment: (1) Please specify the groups that are at play.   It doesn’t have to be the real names you use, just like (I assume) you are using `User.Name` as a placeholder for your actual username.  (2) Please specify more exactly what permission-relevant results you are getting.  Specifically, are the files owned by the group of the `User.Name` account?  What modes are you getting?  I’m guessing 640 and 660, but I can’t tell for sure from your question.  (3) What happens (permissions-wise) when you create files by other means; e.g., `echo foo >` or `echo foo | dd of=`?

Comment: I added examples to the question.  Thanks for the prompting.  Let me know if further details would help.

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail.  (And I guess I should admit that I may have misread the first version of the question.  I was confused by your reference to “cross-account”; I thought you were saying the system was treating `Admin` and `User.Name` differently.  In fact, the question is about getting 600 mode when creating a file in the Unix directory tree versus getting 660 in the Windows directory tree.) … So, anyway, the problem isn’t specific to the `zip` command. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The `+` at the end of the mode for the `/c/Users` files tells me that ACLs are at work.  I’m not sure I’ll be able to answer the question, but here are some suggestions to you: run `getfacl ~/tmp` for both users, run `getfacl /c/Users/Public/tmp`, and look at the permissions of ``C:\Users\Public\tmp`` *in Windows,* and see if you can figure it out from that.  If you’re still stuck, add the output of those commands to your question.  Also, in general (when dealing with permissions problems), I advise you to use `ls -la` and look at what it says for `.`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It sent me on a many-hour reading expedition of file permissions and `getfacl` and added the results to the question.  I did inspect the Windows permissions for the folders containing the newly created files, but the Windows permissions seem more complicated. I recall this being a complication in past Cygwin mailing list threads. I was really hoping that reverse engineering the possible operational processes from the details upward wouldn't be the way to go, and that there would be a high level document explaining it from the top down.

Comment: A bit more: (4) Every file has a UID and a GID (which may sometimes be called “owner” and ”owning group”).  They are the values displayed by ``ls -l`` and `stat`.  They are normally initially set to the UID and GID of the process that creates the file, although there may be exceptions to that.  Recall that a user can belong to multiple groups, and a user’s process will have a primary GID that is (usually) one of those groups.  (See the `id` command.)  The UID and GID of a file can be changed by the `chown` and `chgrp` commands — but that isn’t relevant to your question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) I don’t believe that “`None`” is a special keyword indicating that there is no group.  If you run `getent group`, you may see that “`None`” is simply the name of a group inherited from Windows, like “`SYSTEM`”, “`INTERACTIVE`” and “`Administrators`”.  Cygwin seems to like to use the “`None`” group; I don’t know why.  (6) `group::…` refers to the current GID of the file (or directory).  So, for the files (and directories) in `/home`, `group::…` refers to “`None`”.  But, for `/c/Users/Public/Documents`, it refers to “`SYSTEM`”, because that’s the GID of that directory. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (7) You ask why you aren’t getting execute permission.  See [facl ignoring the "x" permission but only on files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/80216).

Comment: Thank you for the additional pointers, G-Man, including the investigative commands to try and the reason why the `x` bit isn't enabled for files.  The `id` command does indeed show that primary group is `None` for `User.Name` and `Admin`.  Issuing `getent group` yields `None` as the first record, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything about this group online.

Comment: Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/606556) Q&A, `None` also shows up for in the *Windows* file properties, but `lusrmgr.msc` shows no such group, even when run from the `Admin` account.  I can find no tabulation of a `None` group [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-security_groups.html), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-special-identities-groups), or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers).

Comment: What is the issue in putting the files under `/home/` folder so that you do not need to puzzle between Cygwin/Unix permission and Windows ACL ones ? `/c/Users/` is better to be left to pure Windows matter