# Umask questions in mount

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, umask

I have a question regarding 'umask.' I have an extra disk on my Linux system, and I want it to mount during startup with the same permissions as '/home.' For example, my '/home' has these permissions:

```
d rwx r-x r-x  < Directories
- rw- rw- r--  < Files
```

I want any directories or files created on this extra disk to maintain these permissions. My '/etc/fstab' looks like this:

`UUID=BABABABABABA   /path/to/mount   ntfs   umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000   0   2`

And my permissions for both directories and files are currently:

`rwx r-x r-x`

Any suggestions or corrections are appreciated!

Comment: (1) There’s no ``umask`` setting that will give you group-writable files but not group-writable directories. (2) You generally have to go out of your way to get files with executable permission (see [facl ignoring the "x" permission but only on files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/80216)).  Are you actually getting files protected `rwxr-xr-x`?  If so, how are you creating them?

Comment: Instead of `umask=0022` try `dmask=0022,fmask=0113`. Does this help?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You got it, that's exactly what I wanted. The other question you linked also answers my query. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that `dmask=0022,fmask=0113` only works if the filesystem type is some FAT variant, or some other type of filesystem that does not support POSIX-style file permissions natively (e.g. `ntfs`). It's a workaround for missing POSIX permissions support that happens to have a side effect that is suitable to this purpose, not an universal feature of all filesystem types.